# Empty data table- using Beautifulsoup

Tags: json, beautifulsoup

I asked a question earlier regarding an error I was getting. It helped by adding the correct class name for the table on this webpage. However, the code runs but when i print(data), I get an empty response.

```
url = "https://coinmarketcap.com/currencies/bitcoin/historical-data/"
content = requests.get(url).content
soup = BeautifulSoup(content,'html.parser')
table = soup.find('table', {'class': 'cmc-table'})



data = [[td.text.strip() for td in tr.findChildren('td')]
        for tr in table.findChildren('tr')]

print(data)
```

output:

```
C:\Users\Ejer\anaconda3\envs\pythonProject\python.exe C:/Users/Ejer/PycharmProjects/pythonProject/stock_analysis.py
[[], ['No Data']]

Process finished with exit code 0
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### What happens?

Website deals with dynamic content and table is empty in the moment you try to grab the html.

### Solution

```
from selenium import webdriver
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
from time import sleep

browser = webdriver.Chrome('C:\Program Files\ChromeDriver\chromedriver.exe')
browser.get('https://coinmarketcap.com/currencies/bitcoin/historical-data/')
sleep(2)
soup = BeautifulSoup(browser.page_source,'html.parser')

browser.close()


table = soup.find('table', {'class': 'cmc-table'})

[[td.text.strip() for td in tr.findChildren('td')] for tr in table.findChildren('tr')][1:]
```

**Output**

```
[['Jan 09, 2021',
  '$40,788.64',
  '$41,436.35',
  '$38,980.88',
  '$40,254.55',
  '$61,984,162,837',
  '$748,563,483,043'],
 ['Jan 08, 2021',
  '$39,381.77',
  '$41,946.74',
  '$36,838.64',
  '$40,797.61',
  '$88,107,519,480',
  '$758,625,941,267'],
 [...]]
```